# ThreatFox alert on Cloudflare IP

Tags: firewalls, botnet, suricata, indicator-of-compromise

On our company network, suricata just raised the following (single) alert:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2024-01-05T12:42:28.511703+0100",
    "flow_id": 1276412390854359,
    "in_iface": "igb0",
    "event_type": "alert",
    "src_ip": "10.1.1.13",
    "src_port": 53670,
    "dest_ip": "188.114.96.3",
    "dest_port": 443,
    "proto": "TCP",
    "alert": {
        "action": "allowed",
        "gid": 1,
        "signature_id": 91226661,
        "rev": 1,
        "signature": "ThreatFox Cobalt Strike botnet C2 traffic (ip:port - confidence level: 100%)",
        "category": "A Network Trojan was detected",
        "severity": 1,
        "source": {
            "ip": "188.114.96.3",
            "port": 443
        },
        "target": {
            "ip": "10.1.1.13",
            "port": 53670
        },
        "metadata": {
            "confidence_level": [
                "100"
            ],
            "first_seen": [
                "2023_12_31"
            ]
        }
    },
    "flow": {
        "pkts_toserver": 1,
        "pkts_toclient": 0,
        "bytes_toserver": 66,
        "bytes_toclient": 0,
        "start": "2024-01-05T12:42:28.511703+0100"
    }
}
```

This is what I was able to find out:

1. At the time, the user on PC 10.1.1.13 was surfing the web during lunch break (in private mode, so we don't have a browser history). The destination port is 443, so that alert might have been caused by something loaded by his browser.
2. According to whois, 188.114.96.3 is a cloudflare IP.
3. I can't find that IP in the [ThreadFox database UI](https://threatfox.abuse.ch/browse/) (I searched for `ioc:188.114.96.3`).

So while, at a first glance, this looks scary ("botnet C2 traffic ... confidence level: 100%"), I'm tempted to classify this incident as a false positive:

- Cloudflare is a CDN, so it's perfectly possible that the same IP might be used to serve the content of different customers (one of which might have been hacked).
- There are no other alerts or indicators of compromise.

Hence, my questions are:

Q1: Is this assessment reasonable, or should I be more worried?

Q2: Why can't I find the IP address in the ThreadFox database? I can reliably reproduce the suricata alert by trying to access the IP address via https in a browser. The suricata rule is from the abuse.ch.threatfox.rules ruleset (last updated today), and the reference_html URL (https://threatfox.abuse.ch/ioc/1226661/) does not yield useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1: Is this assessment reasonable, or should I be more worried?

Yes, your assessment is correct.

> Q2: Why can't I find the IP address in the ThreadFox database?

Probably because it was quickly deleted, you see, you can not use the IP addresses of Cloudflare as an IOCs because those IPs are shared among thousands of domains (hence, false positives).